# cannot unlink `objects/pack/pack-23879505c4ebc19266f28b149fd52e0aa1e3889a.idx': Permission denied

Tags: windows, git

I am really exhausted in deleting below file although I run code in **administrator** mode. Not sure what is blocking it deleting it. Please help me.  Even I tried to delete file from windows CMD but no success.

```
user@USER-PC /D/Projects/Authorized.net/11/authorize.net/one/.git
$ rm -rf *
rm: cannot unlink `objects/pack/pack-23879505c4ebc19266f28b149fd52e0aa1e3889a.idx': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `objects/pack': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove directory `objects': Directory not empty
```

Here is the list from directory:

```
user@USER-PC /D/Projects/Authorized.net/11/authorize.net/one/.git
$ ls -lart
total 10
drwxr-xr-x    1 prateek  Administ    12288 Apr 19 00:32 objects
drwxr-xr-x    1 prateek  Administ     4096 Apr 19 00:32 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 prateek  Administ     4096 Apr 19 00:58 ..
```

I'm trying to delete local files from present `GIT`.

Comment: Please show the long listing for the file `objects/pack/pack-23879505c4ebc19266f28b149fd52e0aa1e3889a.idx`

Comment: Check the ownership and permissions on the `pack` subdirectory, and check for ACLs and the general sort of SELinux things that make such Linux systems secure and therefore unusable. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give full permission to that file and then you will be able to delete it.

```
user@USER-PC /D/Projects/Authorized.net/11/authorize.net/one/.git
$ chmod 777 .git/
```

then apply remove command

```
$ rm -rf .git/
```

then it will be get removed from machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried deleting this with administrator permissions and it still failed, then that indicates that another program has that pack file open.  This can happen if another Git process gets hung while that file is open, or perhaps another process is scanning the files in that directory, like a virus scanner.

To see what process has that file open, use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) from SysInternals.  Stopping that process will release the lock.  If all else fails, you can reboot, which will also terminate the process, though this is obviously not particularly graceful.

Comment: Not sure though, I had restarted my machine and still it was showing the same. I simply give full permission via 'git bash' and then able to delete it.

Comment: Interesting.  Was this over an SMB share, an NFS mount or any other sort of network filesystem?  Is `D:` really a local hard drive?

Comment: I think it was NFS mount and its a hard drive